# Why is it Called iota?

Tags: c++, c++11, range, numeric, iota

C++11 introduced a function called [`iota`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/iota/). Which "Assigns to every element in the range [first,last) successive values of val, as if incremented with ++val after each element is written."

Can someone explain what "iota" means here though?

I [looked up "iota"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iota) and it seems to have nothing to do with generating a range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) non-authoritative, but nonetheless correct, wiki:

> The function is named after the integer function `⍳` from the programming language APL.

In APL, the `⍳` function (represented with the ninth letter of the Greek alphabet, iota) is used to create a zero-based array of consecutive, ascending integers of a specified length.

Comment: You could go further by explaining to the uninitiated that this symbol is the Greek letter "Iota".

Answer (score 6):

It's a Greek letter used in mathematics to denote a set of consecutive numbers. [Iota use in APL.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols)

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.randomprogramming.com/2014/07/algorithms-in-action-iota-and-shuffle/) has a very plausible-seeming explanation:

> The Greek letter iota is used in the programming language APL to generate a sequence of consecutive integers.